# Angular in Public Subnet and Backend springboot in private subnet without using proxy server(nginx/apache2) how can traffic flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, nginx, reverse-proxy, amazon-elb

My angular 10 is in public subnet ec2 machine where spring-boot in private subnet (front: private ALB). For dev testing i installed an apache2 and with 'proxypass' i was able to call the backend from browser(0.0.0.0/0). But in production i don't want this way, as private hosted micro-services will be accessible from all world(0.0.0.0/0).
ex: which i used in dev so that from browser can connect to the backend private hosted micro-services.

```
 ProxyPass /backend-service-1 http://internal-alb/backend-service-1
ProxyPassReverse /backend-service-1 http://internal-alb/backend-service-1
```

But this way it causes the MZ zone to have connection with public, is there any other recommended approach ?

Comment: You **do** know how SPAs (and Angular) work, right? **There is no alternative** to exposing your backend web-service to the (very public) client - though you _can_ use a reverse-proxy if necessary, but that's just an added complication.

Comment: i really didn't get, right now in the env.ts i added the private alb address but when deployed am getting timeout as private alb are inaccessible from the browser. intiialy my thought was brwoser -->ui(public) -->privatealb -->backend